# I have a file of 30 Gb and my RAM size is 4 Gb only so want to break file into 30 chunk of 1 gb each

Tags: java, r

I'm dealing with a 30 Gb file called "sales.tsv" tab separated file.
I cannot read file of this size directly into R as RAM is 4 GB only.
So, I want to break this file into chunk of 1 GB or 500 MB. 
I`m looking for algorithm or code to do this automatically in R

And process should be like:-  Take file in R , break into chunk and through the output in a .tcv or .cvs  (1 file of 30 GB --> 30 files of 1 GB each)

I`m unable to do this

Any help towards this will be appreciable.

Comment: Open a `FileInputStream` and a `FileOutputStream`, after copying 1Gb of data from the input to the output create a new `FileOutputStream` and move on. The idea is, that the `FileInputStream` only reads a part of the actual file and not the whole file at once.

Comment: If you're using `read.table` or `data.table:::fread`, you can set how many rows to read (`nrows`) and how many to skip (`skip`). A combination of the two enables you to take out selected chunks and save them to files of desirable sizes.

Comment: you could work with java (8) Streams api. `Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("pathToFile");`

Comment: Can any one of you write a short code in R for the same;

Comment: Roman Lustrik,  thanks a lot for suggestion but It would be more appreciable if you could an example or code .
But anyways thanks for the clue

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick . P.S. (1 000 000 000 is the number of bytes in 1GB ).

```
private static String FILE_NAME = "EnterYourFileHere";
private static byte PART_SIZE = 1 000 000 000;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inputFile = new File(FILE_NAME);
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    String newFileName;
    FileOutputStream filePart;
    int fileSize = (int) inputFile.length();
    int nChunks = 0, read = 0, readLength = PART_SIZE;
    byte[] byteChunkPart;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        while (fileSize > 0) {
            if (fileSize <= 1 000 000 000) {
                readLength = fileSize;
            }
            byteChunkPart = new byte[readLength];
            read = inputStream.read(byteChunkPart, 0, readLength);
            fileSize -= read;
            assert (read == byteChunkPart.length);
            nChunks++;
            newFileName = FILE_NAME + ".part"
                    + Integer.toString(nChunks - 1);
            filePart = new FileOutputStream(new File(newFileName));
            filePart.write(byteChunkPart);
            filePart.flush();
            filePart.close();
            byteChunkPart = null;
            filePart = null;
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```